# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONCAT_EQUAL

Tags: php, string, concatenation

```
$XMLFormatedString .= "<Filter id='" .= .$row->id. .="' name='" .= .$row->label. .="'><Label>" .= .$row->label. .="</Label></Filter>";
```

Comment: -1, where is your question? T_CONCAT_EQUAL means '.=', are you aware of that?

Comment: The question made sense to me, +1

Comment: @Adam : no "hello", no sentence, no question mark... it makes sense to me too, but I find it rather rude.

Answer (score 5):

You can't chain the .= operator like that. it's also not nessecary in this case, you can just use the . operator after the first one:

```
$XMLFormatedString .= "<Filter id='" .$row->id. "' name='" .$row->label."'><Label>" .$row->label."</Label></Filter>";
```

also, whatever you're trying to do, it looks like a bad idea. you should use something like [PHP DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to write XML.

Comment: +1. Especially for the DomDocument bit... But fyi: you can chain the `.=` operator in general.  `$f = 'f'; $o = 'o'; $f .= $o .= 'obar';` will end with `$f == 'foobar'` and `$o == 'oobar'`.  But you can't have a static string (non-variable) anywhere to the left of the `.=`...

Answer (score 3):

The left hand side of an [assignment operator](http://php.net/language.operators.assignment) like `.=` needs to be a variable. But in this case `"<Filter id='"` is not a variable.

I guess you meant the normal [string concatenation operator `.`](http://php.net/language.operators.string):

```
$XMLFormatedString .= "<Filter id='" . $row->id . "' name='" . $row->label . "'><Label>" . $row->label . "</Label></Filter>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple syntax errors:

```
 .= "<Filter id='" .= .$row->id.
```

Should be:

```
 .= "<Filter id='".$row->id.
```

etc...